# AWS ECS fails to start windows on Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, docker-for-windows

According to the new AWS feature https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/10/aws-fargate-amazon-ecs-windows-containers/. Trying to launch my windows fails with the following:  CannotCreateVolumeError: unsupported: Dockerfile contains VOLUME instruction. Volumes are not configured in task definiuton, nor Dockerfile. Any ideas why this may happen?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was connected with [jenkins-docker-agent](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-agent/blob/master/11/windows/windowsservercore-ltsc2019/Dockerfile#L81) (same for [docker-inbound-agent](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-inbound-agent)) parent image. The failute occurs because these images contain the VOLUME instruction.

For this specific case you will need to use something like:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:11.0.13_8-jdk-windowsservercore-1809
```

My solution here is the content of  jenkins-docker-agent image BUT without VOLUME layers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is reading this, the solution was to NOT use the default Windows images at https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/inbound-agent. These images are actually built from https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-inbound-agent/tree/master/11/windows/windowsservercore-ltsc2019 (this image does not have Volume instructions), which was built from https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-agent/blob/master/11/windows/windowsservercore-ltsc2019/Dockerfile (this one does have Volume instruction). There are variations of it including "nanoserver" and "jdk8/jdk11" versions but they all have Volume instructions which I think these will work on EC2 but not Fargate.

If you want it to work on Fargate, you will need to build a custom image based off of these two Dockerfiles above. I use a multi-stage Dockerfile and commented out the Volume instructions on the first Dockerfile and concatenate the second Dockerfile contents to it.

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:11.0.13_8-jdk-windowsservercore-1809 AS jenkins-agent-windows-builder

...

#VOLUME ${AGENT_ROOT}/.jenkins
#VOLUME ${AGENT_WORKDIR}

...

FROM jenkins-agent-windows-builder
```